# Proof of the maximum singular of matrices of type $\frac{yy^T}{y^Ty}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For arbitrary nonzero vectors $y\in\mathcal{R}^n$, how to prove maximum singular value of matrix $\frac{yy^T}{y^Ty}$ is equal to 1 ?

Comment: You mean singular value or eigenvalue? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, $yy^T$ has a eigenvector $y$ of eigenvalue $y^Ty$, since $(yy^T)y=(y^Ty)y$.
On the other hand, for any $x \in R^n$
$$
||yy^Tx|| = |y^Tx| \cdot ||y|| \leq ||y||^2 \cdot ||x||
$$
But $||y||^2 = y^Ty$. So $y^Ty$ is the maximal eigenvalue of $yy^T$.

If you want a deeper inspection, you can see Frobenius-Perron Theorem about non-negative matrices.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, the matrix $yy^\top$ is symmetric.

The matrix $yy^\top$ has rank $1$, you can prove it by writing it column-wise as $[y_1 y |\cdots| y_n y]$.
Therefore, $n-1$ of its eigenvalues (with algebraic multiplicities) are equal to $0$.

You can also prove that
$$ (yy^\top) y = (y^\top y) y,$$
so that the last eigenvalue is $y^\top y$.

This matrix being symmetric and positive semi-definite, its eigenvalues are its singular values.

More generally, there exists a [min-max principle for singular values](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Min-max_principle_for_singular_values).